# Adding a PNG Logo on the Object

Tags: materials

I'm in the process of making a 3d hoodie with a custom materials and logo on the font of the hoodie. My issue is - the outside part of the logo that I have added to the front of the hoodie is black even though the logo is png. **Why is it black, any nodes I should add?** My future goal is to add more(different) logo on the same spot and animate them, create a transition between them with some noise texture etc. With screenshot #1 logo doesn't work. Screenshot #2 it works but with combination with a different texture. Ask as many questions as you need. I'm new to blender.

Idea; The whole scene is hoodie walking in a loop with its logo changing with some cool animations or morphism effect.

EDITED* So after playing a little bit I have figured out a way to combine main texture with the logo. yay!

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: UV's, I've used Marvelous Designer to create the hoodie with realistic physics, UV Map was created there and works fine in Blender]
[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: EDITED*]

Comment: Since you're viewing through Material Preview mode (which uses EEVEE as a render engine), you must change the materials _Blend Mode_ (scroll down in material properties panel) to something other than _Opaque_ (Alpha Blend works well for most situations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first image ...
+1 Christopher's comment ... *Eevee* - *Alpha* other than *Opaque* under material properties.

For your second image ...
It is correct solution of mixing if logo will the same material (like fabric diffuse kind)

For your fourth image ...
Your Mix Shader is mixing Principled and Transparent shader. With Factor set 1 means upper socket with Principled is blender's logic bellow Transparent plugged into lower socket that is handled by blender as layer above. Since Factor is 1 it fully propagates shader plugged in lower socket.

Image texture node (or its modified string) should be connected to *Factor* socket of *Mix Shader* node used as Factor (mask).

[image]
[image]

Specific to your needs - I don't thing you need Transparent shader at all.

It depends on your needs or chosen workflow, but you would be just fine with

- setup in your second image or
- two principled shaders (one for fabric material and one for logo material) and image )logo) use as factor for mixing these two materials.

[image]
[image]

To animate appearance of several logos I would create black and white animated texture (video or image sequence) and use it as factor for material mix.

Or you can do it in blender by keyframed *Factor* value of *Mix > Colour* node ...

[image]

... and use it as Factor (mask) in the same way. Also here you can animate transitions drive by some texture node or any other factor.

Or you can render object without logo (fully fabric, no transparency), than render object only with logo with transparent rest of the scene (each logo = solo render animation) and mix them in post pro (compositor) with specific transition.

Range of possibilities is too wide ... :)